# Negation of request.is_ajax()?

Tags: django, django-views

I want to write the negation of request.is_ajax() but im not sure how to do so.
can u say request.isnot_ajax() ?? how would u do this in python?

Comment: If your problem is solved by one of the answers suggested by other users, please mark as teh accepted answer by clicking on the tick next to the question.  This rewards other stackoverflow users for their time spent helping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's python. Since the method returns a boolean, negate it like any other:

```py
if not request.is_ajax():
    do_some_non_ajax_stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if not request.is_ajax():
    #do smth
```

?